# Fastest way to find nearest nonzero value in array from columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, numpy, optimization

I am looking for the nearest nonzero cell in a numpy 3d array based on the i,j,k coordinates stored in a pandas dataframe. My solution below works, but it is slower than I would like. I know my optimization skills are lacking, so I am hoping someone can help me find a faster option.

It takes 2 seconds to find the nearest non-zero for a 100 x 100 x 100 binary array, and I have hundreds of files, so any speed enhancements would be much appreciated!

```
a=np.random.randint(0,2,size=(100,100,100))
# df with i,j,k of interest
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100,size=(100,3)).tolist(),
                columns=['i','j','k'])

def find_nearest(a,df):
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import time
    t0=time.time()
    nzi = np.nonzero(a)
    for i,r in df.iterrows():
        dist = ((r['k'] - nzi[0])**2 + \
              (r['i'] - nzi[1])**2 + \
              (r['j'] - nzi[2])**2)
        nidx = dist.argmin()
        df.loc[i,['nk','ni','nj']]=(nzi[0][nidx],
                                    nzi[1][nidx],
                                    nzi[2][nidx])
    print(time.time()-t0)
    return(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you are trying to solve looks like a **nearest-neighbor search**.

The worst-case complexity of the current code is `O(n m)` with `n` the number of point to search and `m` the number of neighbour candidates. With `n = 100` and `m = 100**3 = 1,000,000`, this means about hundreds of million iterations. To solve this efficiently, one can use a **better algorithm**.

The common way to solve this kind of problem consists in putting all elements in a [BSP-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning) data structure (such as [Quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) or [Octree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree). Such a data structure helps you to locate the nearest elements near a location in a `O(log(m))` time. As a result, the overall complexity of this method is `O(n log(m))`! SciPy already [implement KD-trees](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html).

**Vectorization** generally also help to speed up the computation.

```py
def find_nearest_fast(a,df):
    from scipy.spatial import KDTree
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import time
    t0=time.time()
    candidates = np.array(np.nonzero(a)).transpose().copy()
    tree = KDTree(candidates, leafsize=1024, compact_nodes=False)
    searched = np.array([df['k'], df['i'], df['j']]).transpose()
    distances, indices = tree.query(searched)
    nearestPoints = candidates[indices,:]
    df[['nk', 'ni', 'nj']] = nearestPoints
    print(time.time()-t0)
    return df
```

This implementation is **16 times faster** on my machine. Note the results differ a bit since there are multiple nearest points for a given input point (with the same distance).